# Trocar .html e css caso seja mobile ao invés de usar o m.mysite

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

to precisando trocar .html e css caso seja mobile ao invés de usar o m.mysite usando codigo, tem como ?

Comment: Cara depende. Vc configurou como o m.site? Primeira coisa a fazer é evitar o direcionamento para o m.site... É esse o seu problema ou o seu problema é com Media Queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma forma é adicionar CSS´s específicos para cada resolução.

Algumas formas de informar CSS´s para resoluções diferentes:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="mobiel-device.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)" href="ipad.css" />
```

Você pode adicionar diferentes arquivos CSS para cada resolução que precisar.

É importante adicionar essa tag no cabeçalho também para que a largura da página seja iniciada com a escala correta:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
```